# There is a linkerror when I use opengl in Qt5, about gluOrtho2D

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qt5

I have try all solutions appeared on the web, but the error still exist.
Here are the error information:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _gluOrtho2D@16 referenced in function "protected: virtual void __thiscall widget::initializeGL(void)" (?initializeGL@widget@@MAEXXZ)
```

I am sure that I have included all the head files correctly, and link files are in their right position, and I also add `#define GLUT_DISABLE_ATEXIT_HACK` in my file. Besides, when I didn't use Qt, every thing is OK. While I put my code into QGLWidget, the error appeared! 
Any more, I noticed that the error information after `_gluOrtho2D@` is 16, not 32 as other's on the web...
Why? How to correct them?

Comment: Are you including glu32.lib? The linker cannot find the code for that function that QT is using in its widget. You seem to have specified the correct header, but not the library.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question regarding the **16** following the decorated `_gluOrhto2D@`, that is the size of the argument list you are passing (in bytes) when using the `__stdcall` calling convention.

Considering `gluOrtho2D (...)` is supposed to take 4 `GLdouble` arguments and `GLdouble` is supposed to be a 64-bit type something seems seriously wrong (the proper decorated name is `_gluOrtho2D@32`).

Did you by any chance confuse your compiler by attempting to pass `gluOrtho2D (...)` 4 `GLfloat` / `float` variables and/or re-define the prototype for `gluOrtho2D (...)` anywhere?